# Powershell: how to passthrough variable value, which is valued inside executed command variable

Tags: powershell

It is a bit tricky to explain what I need, but please take a look of below simplified code example to understand, such approach is needed to execute script in 64 bit mode in very specific circumstances:

```
$x=0
$command = {
 $a=1
 $b=2
 $x=$a

 $r=$a+$b
}

$Result = C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command $command
write-host($x)
```

Final results of this $command execution is 3, but I need also passthrough $x value, what is valued inside $command, in current example $x=0 in the end.

My question is, is there any possibility to passthrough variables values, which are valued inside command variable? In above example, is it possible to passthrough $a and $b variables values?

Comment: Do you want your output `$Result` to contain both object `$a` and the other object `$b` or do you want to pass `$a`and `$b` into this command?

Comment: edited a bit my question, could you please take a look, hopefully it is a bit more understandable now :)

Comment: Are you realy calling whole new instance of powershell from within powershell or is it rather a function or scriptBock? In functions you could play with scopes and calling by reference to achieve this. However I think in new instances that won't be possible. All you could do would be to return a collection (array / hashtable) that contains all the results.

Comment: Your command scriptblock produces no output. What did you expect to capture in $Result? I think you should explain more of what you're trying to achieve and you'll certainly get some helpful answers. "Pass through $a and $b variable values" - to what? To where? What are you actually trying to achieve??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're calling PowerShell from within PowerShell but:

```
PS> $command = {
$a=1
$b=2

Return $a+$b
}

$x = & $command

$x

3
```

You can execute the Command Variable with the call (&) operator and get your result.

HTH

Comment: return was actually what worked for my case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what X=0 and the write-host have to do with running the command in another process and retrieving results from it. Your command scriptblock creates no output in it's current state and therefore nothing will be captured to `$Result`

It seems like you intended to do a calculation with `$a` and `$b` but then say you want to pass the values of those out. Do you want to calculate internally and then just output what they were originally? You can simply output a hashtable or pscustomobject and use that output like this.

```
$command = {
    $a=1
    $b=2
    $x=$a

    $r = $a + $b
    @{A=$a;B=$b}
}
$Result = C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command $command

$Result

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
A                              1                                                                                                                                                              
B                              2    

$result.a

1
```